# Repeated within family measurements in an lmer

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, biostatistics

I'm trying to model in R, how lizard head size (Continuous) can be predicted by mass (Continuous), hatch time (Factor: Early vs Late), and Clutch mass (Continuous), with Family as a random factor. An example model would be:

```r
model <- lmer(log(Head) ~ log(Mass) + Hatch_time + Clutch_mass + 
                          (1|Family), data = dat)
```

However, there is a problem. My `Clutch_mass' continuous variable is repeated within each family, as within family clutch mass is the same. There are 12 individuals from each family, meaning each clutch mass value is repeated 12 times. How could I include this variable in my model, whilst avoiding replication?

Comment: This shouldn't cause a problem. Are you getting a problem trying to run this model? You can adjust for between- and within- cluster level effects as fixed effects, and still the random effect will simply model the residual variation according to the covariance structure - in this case a random intercept for Family.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm having no problem running the model, I was just worried that having 12 duplicate clutch mass values for each family (100 families in total) would cause problems in the model. So the random intercept for family will mediate this?

Comment: You only lose one degree of freedom by adjusting for clutch_mass, and, unless doing so perfectly explains all the residual variation, it should be possible to adjust for a random intercept for Family. Surely there are other unmeasured genetic or phenotypic correlates of headsize, it's just that the variance of the random intercept will be less by adjusting for clutch mass.

Comment: Thankyou! Excuse my lack of common sense, but does this mean my original model is potentially fine, and would account for the carcass mass duplication in my data?

Answer (score 1):

As @AdamO said in comments, having a predictor variable that's the same for all members of a group isn't a problem in a mixed model "unless doing so perfectly explains all the residual variation," which isn't likely in biological studies. To that extent, your "original model is potentially fine."

That doesn't, however, remove the need to evaluate whether you have the proper functional form for your model. For example, I wonder why you are modeling `log(Head)` as a linear function of `Clutch_mass` (presumably the sum of all `Mass` values for a clutch) while you model it as a function of the individual's `log(Mass)`. More generally, flexible fits of continuous predictor variables with regression splines or generalized additive models can be more useful unless there's a theoretical reason to expect that a log or other transformation is appropriate.